# How to get android gradient color for position?

Tags: android, gradient

I'm using GradientDrawable as follows:

```
line1.setBackground(new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT, new int[]{fromColor, toColor}));
```

How can i get gradient color for position (within [0,1]), let's say 0,8?

Comment: What you mean `for position`? What the position you mean?

Comment: let's say 'fromColor' is position is 0, 'toColor' position is 1.0

Comment: Did you see this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/26503744/2956344

Comment: it does not look like an answer to my question